# SQL Leetcode Hard Question Failing 1 case

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

Preparing for a data science interview and ran into this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/trips-and-users/description/). My code is passing all of the test cases except for one.

Can someone help explain why my code doesn't work for this question
Thanks

Here is my code:

```
# total rides by unbanned users by day
with total_rides as (SELECT t.request_at as day,
count(1) as total_rides
from trips t  join 
users u on t.client_id = u.users_id and u.banned = 'No' and request_at between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-03'
group by 1),

# cancelled rides by unbanned users by day
cancelled_rides as (
SELECT t.request_at as day,
count(1) as cancelled_rides
from trips t join 
users u on t.client_id = u.users_id  
where t.status like 'cancelled%'and u.banned = 'No' and request_at between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-03'
group by 1
),

combined as(select tr.day, tr.total_rides as total_rides, cr.cancelled_rides as cancelled_rides  from cancelled_rides cr
right join total_rides tr on cr.day = tr.day)

select day, case when cancelled_rides is NULL then 0
else round(cancelled_rides/total_rides,2) end as "cancellation rate"
from combined
```

Here is the test case:

```
| id   | client_id | driver_id | city_id | status    | request_at |
| ---- | --------- | --------- | ------- | --------- | ---------- |
| 1111 | 1         | 10        | 1       | completed | 2013-10-01 |
```

```
| users_id | banned | role   |
| -------- | ------ | ------ |
| 1        | No     | client |
| 10       | Yes    | driver |
```

```
Output
| day        | cancellation rate |
| ---------- | ----------------- |
| 2013-10-01 | 0                 |
```

```
Expected
| Day | Cancellation Rate |
| --- | ----------------- |
```

Comment: Why do you expect no rows?  The problem calls for a row for each day with rides for unblocked users.  You do want to format with two decimals, not just round to two decimals, though.

Comment: seems I am wrong; the question clearly shows expecting output of e.g. 0.00, 0.50, but in fact expects just 0, 0.5, so round instead of format is appropriate

Comment: ah, your problem is it wants you to exclude trips where either the client or driver is banned.  so the sample data has no days to report

Comment: hmmm interesting, i totally missed that. With that being the case can you help me understand why my code doesnt adequately cover this? I added a where clause that takes out trips made by banned users

Comment: you check banned clients; you need to also check banned drivers

Comment: Thanks so much. Would you be able to point me towards how i would do that in the code? Struggling a bit

Comment: Just add another join of users only on driver_id and with a different alias

Comment: Your solution is much more complicated than necessary, you just need conditional aggregation for this, not any subqueries